# ADB device list doesn't show BackBarry priv

Tags: usb, android, adb

I have Uninstalled and reinstalled ADB. I made sure debug mode was enabled in dev options. And that its on file transfer.
I don't get a propped for enabling debug mode on my device.
The notification claims its already enabled.
And I have tried

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server 
sudo adb devices
adb usb
```

so what now? is this a Driver problem?
I also tried a different USB port with no luck.
Although I am able to transfer files from my device to my computer with no issue.
Tell me whatever info you need me to post about this.

Comment: You **can** check whether or not debug mode is enabled. And, BTW, it's Blackberry...

Comment: Yeah but its running "Android 6.0.1" so it says